# Visual Studio vertical scroll bar markers hidden by resharper?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2019

I am missing the markers for breakpoint and bookmarks in the vertical scroll bar of my Visual Studio. If I suspend my Resharper in the Visual Studio settings, then I can enable the missings marks by checking **Scrollbars > Show annotations over vertical scroll bar > Show marks**.

But if I enabled resharper again, my markers are gone again.

- Why are the markers hidden by resharper?
- How can I restore them?

---

Environment:

- ReSharper Version: Ultimate 2020.1
- Visual Studio Version:
  Professional 2019 (Version 16.5.4)

Comment: Those markers seem to work for me. Do you have the `Resharper`->`Options`->`Environment`->`Editor`->`Appearance`->`Marker Bar` option set to "Integrate marker bar into the enhanced scroll bar (since Visual Studio 2013)"?

Comment: @PiersMyers: Yes I have the option (it is selected). But my problem is, that the "normal" visual studio option under "Options > Text Editor > C# > Scrollbars > Show annotations over vertical scroll bar" is always unselected. If I select it, the markers were shown for one sewcond and then disappear again...

Comment: This is strange, do you run more than one instance of Visual Studio (logged in as yourself) on different computers as it might be related to how your shared settings get stored in the cloud.

Comment: @PiersMyers: No. I am running only one instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you selected the `Fix Silently` value for the `Do not show annotations over vertical scroll bar` option here `ReSharper | Options | Environment | Performance Guide`. Change it to the `Ignore` value.

Answer (score 1):

Even I don't use ReSharper at the moment and I had the option `Show annotations over vertical scroll bar` enabled for all languages, the bar markers were still hidden.

**Image-1**
[image]

The solution was to enable the 'Show annotations over vertical scroll bar` option for the language I use (C# in my case): Options->Text Editor->C#->Scroll Bars

**Image-2**
[image]